Troubleshooting Internet connection, PC "can" connect to Internet, but can't browse normally
I need to troubleshoot what's happening in my network for the past two months. I don't even know what the cause could be.
So, two months prior, when I was just using my computer as usual, the internet was suddenly cut off. It was normal since I live with bad ISP uptime. But I tried my usual solution of resetting, restarting, and seeing if the DNS is up. I couldn't find the cause, so we called the ISP to troubleshoot it. They came, suddenly it worked again without them doing anything to it. I figured that it's just a coincidence. They went back and I did my thing again.
One night, there was a huge lightning strike near my home, and from what I know it fried our modem, but the router was fine. We asked the ISP to replace the modem, and with some ups and downs, -because the lightning also strikes their network-, it went live again.
For the past month, it's been excruciating. The internet felt like it's really slow and barely connecting. What's weird is - the wifi is fine, but the Ethernet was screwed. We re-called the ISP, and they replaced the router, and it still couldn't work.
So, the symptoms are:
It technically can connect to the internet when I checked by pinging 8.8.8.8 but when used for normal browsing like google.com it just confused and can barely load the page.
The DNS is working; it can search domains.
I can remotely go to the PC that's connected to said network THROUGH INTERNET, but I cannot browse internet in the remote connection.
I used ZeroTier network to test to see if the network is still reachable with virtual ethernet, and I can ping from my laptop to the PC through internet.
(network setup attached below).
Now the weird part is, there are only two PC that's connected to the ethernet. The rest are connected to the wifi. Everything connected to wifi is fine and has working internet connection, but these two ethernet PC is screwing one another. One PC may have really nice connection, but the other is screwed, and vice versa. If one computer has the issue, the other will be free from the torment.
This is roughly my network setup:
Routing
In a nutshell, this is what's confusing in one image:
Example
I can access the PC through Anydesk, I can ping 8.8.8.8 but not the google.com, and I can't browse even though I am connected with Anydesk through internet.
Usual cause has been ruled out like IP clash, DNS, ISP trouble, modem and router issue (both has been replaced with a new one), browser issue... I need a new idea to solve this.
Can one faulty cable affect two computer that's not directly connected through wired but roughly connected via router? This is my best guess, you guys probably had similar issue and can help me.
Thanks.

you're showing that you have 2 routers, and the 2 pcs are wired to the second one and having issues.  whats the setup between the 2 routers like

@TimmyBrowne It's only the one yellow LAN port on the Cisco Router to WAN port on the TP-Link, nothing more in-between,
